# Android dev - how to create buttons on the home screen that lead to actions

Tags: android

I just compiled and ran the hello world app and it worked. And I read through a bunch of stuff on the android documentation about the diff components of android and how it all works together.  Now I want to make a few buttons which link to various actions.

For example, I want to make a button that goes to a new screen.  Is there a tutorial for this sort of a thing?  Or maybe someone could explain to me how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really simple.  To make a button that goes to a new screen you should put a new button on your XML layout, and assign it an id. After you've done this, in your code, you need to do something like the following:

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
      CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Also, be sure that the activity that you're trying to start A) Exists, and B) is in your manifest.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If I just code up a new button, will the system just place the code for it into that central xml file that has all the components?

Comment: you need to put the button on your layout xml. I'm not sure what you've called it, but it's probably refered to in your code by something such as "R.layout.yourXmlNameHere".

By Manifest I mean AndroidManifest.xml  You can add new activities in the GUI or you can do `<activity android:name=".yourActivityName"></activity>`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html Have a look at that.

Comment: You are reaching out to the XML and finding the right button so that you can hang some code on it.  Up at the top, where it says "findViewById(R.id.mybutton), that is how you link to the button defined in the XML description.

Answer (score 2):

The [Form stuff tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html) is really useful. I believe that's the next thing you want to learn after HelloWorld.

To start a new screen call `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, depending if you intend to get data back from the new activity. You also want to learn something called [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html), which you can add information to it and pass between screens(or activity). Using intents are most often used for stating a new activity ([Android dev Guide for Acticities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)).

Hope that's helpful.